# Compile string cases into list

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a html formatted string:

```
s = "<span class=\"ads__unit__content__details\"> <span>Data I want to extract</span> </span> <p class=\"ads__unit__content__keys\"> \
<span>More data I want to extract</span> <span>Even more data I want to extract</span> </p> <p>"
```

I am trying to extract the different parts using a string pattern:

```
StringCases[s, "<span>"~~x__~~"</span>"-> x]
```

But this somehow just works on the outermost tag pairs. This is the resulting output:

```
    {"<span>Data I want to extract</span> </span> <p \class=\"ads__unit__content__keys\"> <span>More data I want to \
extract</span> <span>Even more data I want to extract</span>"}
```

Why does it ignore the

```
</span>
```

tags in the middle of the string? I would expect a list with all the substrings separated..

Comment: How about `ImportString[s, "HTML"]`?

Comment: I have tried that @sjoerd-smit, but it gives me an error saying that the requested webpage needs javascript to function. Although I must admit it is weird because the string is displayed properly before trying to re-import it with ImportString..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringCases[s, "<span>" ~~ Shortest[x___] ~~ "</span>" -> x]
```

> {"Data I want to extract", "More data I want to extract", "Even more data I want to extract"}

[`Shortest >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Shortest.html):

> - ***If no explicit* Shortest *or* Longest *is given, ordinary expression patterns are normally effectively assumed to be* Shortest[p], *while string patterns are assumed to be* Longest[p].**

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I was not aware of this option with patterns